# Create new Powerpoint presentation based on selected slides in current presentation

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

I want the script to use the currently selected slides in the current presentation, and create a new presentation using those slides. This is what I'm trying, but can't get the syntax for copying the slides correct (the various commented lines).

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    set thisPresentation to active presentation
    --copy object slide 5 of active presentation -- of thisPresentation
    --set selectedSlides to slide range of selection of active window
    --copy slide range of selection of active window

    set newPresentation to make new presentation
    paste object newPresentation

    close newPresentation saving yes
end tell
```

Comment: Can't help with the Applescript part, but if I were trying to do this in VB/VBA, I'd store the indices of the selected slides in an array, collection or string variable;  save a copy of the presentation;  in the copy of the presentation step through it backwards and delete any slide whose index is not included in the array/collection.

Answer (score 3):

Blimey, was a dumb omission. The command is 'copy object', not just 'copy'.

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    copy object slide range of selection of active window

    set newPresentation to make new presentation
    paste object newPresentation
end tell
```

I knew it should work.